# FTP account for every system user

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, configuration

I am for the first time venturing on server configurations, I'm using Ubuntu.

I created a script that I give a `domain name` and a `password` that automatically makes the following functions:

- User creation in the system.
- User directory creation in the `home` folder.
- Create the folder `public` within the newly created user directory.
- Creation of the `index.html` file of welcome in the `public` folder of the user.
- Creation of custom configuration of Virtual Host Nginx file.
- Restart Nginx to start the new Virtual Host.

And now I have the following goal:

- For every new user created by the script, also **create a customized FTP 'server/user' for that user** and give access only to its own directory inside the folder `home` in the system.

But all content found on the internet only speaks of the creation of a *single FTP user*. Do you know any way to do something like this?

Comment: are you running vsftp?

Comment: Most of ftp servers have chroot capability